# How to use single instance of QLPreviewController to view multiple Powerpoint Presentation coming from server?

Tags: ios

Any idea on how to use QLPreiviewController for multiple PPT's ariving through server.??

Answer (score 2):

Put your documents' urls in an array and implement the two methods from [QLPreviewControllerDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewControllerDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009665) protocol.  There is an example from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010052).